# cypress .each() .wrap() .invoke('text') takes long time

Tags: performance, html-table, cypress, e2e-testing, invoke

I am trying to check the items shown in my table for some assertions. My way is to put all of the items in an array and then iterate over that array.

My problem: All assertions already passed but the cypress runner still takes a lot of time to finish the cy.wrap(.invoke(text)) jobs.

Since this is a very core command of my cypress tests it would be great to have a more efficient function.

My command:

```
cy.get('table tbody').within(() => {
        cy.get('tr').each((tr) => {
            cy.wrap(tr.children().eq(index)).invoke('text').then((text) => {
                text = text.trim();
                arrayWithValuesOfTheList.push(text);
            });
        })
            .then(() => {
                //in here all the (quickly passing) assertions are...
            });
    });
```

Thanks for any help in advance. I appreciate you all!

Comment: What are you asserting the values of the `arrayWithValuesOfTheList` with ?

Comment: It depends on the input of the command. For example matching them with a regex pattern.

Comment: You are also pass an index as an argument for your callback function in `.each()`. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#DOM-Elements

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid wrapping the value, will give some increase in speed but it's hard to say what is the slowest part.

```js
const arrayWithValuesOfTheList  = []
cy.get('table tbody tr')
  .each($tr => {
    arrayWithValuesOfTheList.push($tr.children().eq(index).text())
  })
  .then(() => {
    //in here all the (quickly passing) assertions are...
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert on **individual cells**, using `.each($cell => {...})` is fine but if you want whole-column assertions (e.g sorted, unique-values) it gets difficult with `.each()`.

To build something adaptable for various tests, take a look at the pattern here [Sorting the table](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/07/27/sorting-the-table/#sorting).

The idea is to create helper functions using `.map()` to selected table rows and columns.

```js
const { _ } = Cypress

// helpers, reusable
const getColumn = (colIndex) => {
  return (rows$) => {
    const children$ = _.map(rows$, 'children')
    return _.map(children$, `[${colIndex}]`)
  }
}

const toStrings = (cells$) => _.map(cells$, 'textContent')

const toNumbers = (texts) => _.map(text, Number)


cy.get('table tbody tr')    // rows of table
  .then(getColumn(1))       // extract 2nd column
  .then(toStrings)          // get the text value
  .then(toNumbers)          // convert if assertions require numeric values

  // whole-column assertion example
  .should(values => {
    const sorted = _.sortBy(values)
    expect(values, 'cells are sorted ').to.deep.equal(sorted)
  })

  // individual value assertion
  .should(values => {
    values.forEach(value => {
      expect(value).to.be.lt(100)
    })
  })
```

---

**Addressing performance issue**

If performance is poor, you can reduce the number of process steps at the Cypress command level by using jQuery-only commands.

This will avoid adding commands to the Cypress queue which is likely to be the slowest part

```js
const arrayWithValuesOfTheList  = []
cy.get('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)')    // 2nd col of each row
  .then($tds => {                           // only jQuery methods inside
    $tds.text((index, cellText) => {        
      arrayWithValuesOfTheList.push(cellText.trim())
    })
  })
  .then(() => {
    //in here all the (quickly passing) assertions are...
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. It gets the `tr` values one by one and matches in against a regex pattern.

```js
cy.get('table tbody tr').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele.text().trim())
    .should('match', /myregexp/)
    .and('not.include', 'some text')
})
```

Comment: It is more than just one assertion, but this looks very clean.

Comment: You can add `and` to apply multiple assertions. Updated the answer.